# sending parameters to void objective c,iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, selector

This won't work, I have  NSMutableArray - uidslist and need to sent it to the doAfterRequestComplete as urlString, how I can do it?

Please help me, I'm new in objective c

```
[uidstr performSelector:@selector(doAfterRequestComplete:) ];
```

.m

```
-(void)doAfterRequestComplete:(NSMutableString *)urlString
{
    NSLog(@"%@",urlString);
}
```

.h

```
-(void)doAfterRequestComplete:(NSMutableString *)urlString;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the object (and call it on the object with this method, probably self):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doAfterRequestComplete:) withObject: uidstr];
```